# Ruby on rails - why params[:name] is null when trying to get a select tag option value in the controller

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, controller, html-select

My code is like:

```
In .html :

<div class="sub-field">
        <%= label_tag 'Prod: ' %><br>
        <%= select_tag 'prod_name', options_for_select(@prods), {:id=> 'prod_select', :style=> "width:25%"}%>
</div>


In .rb : 

name = params[:prod_name]
```

name gives null when actually there is a value selected on front-end.
How can I get the really selected value from the dropdown selection in the controller?

Comment: What's in `@prods`?

Comment: @smathy, it is instance variable and store values queried from database.

Comment: Edit your question to show the contents of it in your context above, eg. do a `Rails.logger.debug @prods.inspect` in the controller action that populates the view, and then copy/paste that from your logs into your question.

Comment: Hi @smathy, I have added `Rails.logger.debug prods.inspect` to html, and it shows true on the browser, I am new to rails, is this what you mean? Thanks. I can see prod has all the values for option, but when I select one of them, I want to get the selected one in controller. However, this one in controller shows null.

Comment: @smathy,  in the log , `prods` is also nil, the values `prods` got is queried from database upon a selection event. In the browser, it is not nil.

Comment: Can you show us the rendered HTML so we can see what the selection and options look like? Does `@prods` contain a list of names and IDs?